# Find Cell Value and then input Timestamp 3 columns to the right (Excel Form-Button)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script for Excel that connects a form button to enter the provided information into cells. So Far everything works. However, I want to add a button that will look into a txtbox content named "UserID" (me.UserID.value), search for it on the spreadsheet, and then place a time stamp on the 7th column and same row. `.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")` rightnow enters the time in time and I need to input the time out.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("WalkIns")
' Fined Empty row
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

' Make sure slots aren't left blank
If Trim(Me.FName.Value) = "" Then
  Me.FName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter your first name"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.LName.Value) = "" Then
  Me.LName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter your last name"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.UName.Value) = "" Then
  Me.UName.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter your Username (Example: XXXXXX)"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.RFVisit.Value) = "" Then
  Me.RFVisit.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter your reason for visiting the Walk-Up Window"
  Exit Sub
End If

' Enter responses into spreadsheet
With ws

  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.FName.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.LName.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.UName.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.RFVisit.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")

End With

Me.FName.Value = ""
Me.LName.Value = ""
Me.UName.Value = ""
Me.RFVisit.Value = ""

Me.FName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

I am probably really overthinking this.

Comment: I tried the below code but no luck...I'm, missing something.


`Private Sub ExitButton_Click()


Columns("D:D").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=Me.UsId.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
.Offset(0, 3) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")

'If cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something

'Else
    'do it another thing
'End If

End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be after this

```
Private Sub ExitButton_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("D1", Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=Me.UsId.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "UserID '" & Me.UsId.Value & "' not found!", vbExclamation
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 3) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I just started using VBA script (4 days ago)so I have to learn a lot. The script you provided worked wonderfully but now I have the issue were it does it for the fist cell it finds with the Me.UsId.Value and not the last. It overwrites the timestamp on the first "FabMar" value instead of the last.

Comment: Well, being a new issue you should post a new question with all relevant info and (maybe) your data screenshot. As for now My understanding is you either need a loop to go through all usid value occurrences or an AutoFilter to filter such occurrences

Comment: I did :) but I figured that adding `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` will work for now. There's always room to learn though. 

Once again, Thank you ^_^

Comment: So you needed to timestamp by the last value only. Yes, that is the way.